# How to get the location of the user folders on Mac OS X using Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

How to get the location of the file in mac os using objective c?

`/Users/objc/Downloads/x.pdf`

Any foundation classes for this?

please give me some sample code.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure whether I understand what you want, but you get the user's home directory with:

```
NSArray *docDirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                    NSDownloadsDirectory,
                    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *doc = [docDirs objectAtIndex:0];
```

And then you can construct the path:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/x.pdf", doc];
```

Comment: The cleaner way is to use stringByAppendingPathComponent:. NSString *path = [doc stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"x.pdf"];, which will automatically insert the directory separation character.

Comment: Also, you want `NSDownloadsDirectory`, not `NSDocumentationDirectory`. (Note that `NSDocumentationDirectory` is usually `~/Library/Documentation`, which is different from `NSDocumentDirectory`, which is `~/Documents`.)

Comment: @mipadi: Thanks for catching my mistake regarding `NSDocumentationDirectory` (copy&paste error). Edited my answer.